# -2147217900:[MySQL 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.7.22-log] error in VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have a VBA code and I am currently trying to push data 
The data is below

```
Name     Analyst     Method    condition
AAA       AAA        AAA       Automated
```

When I try to push the data using VBA Code I am receiving this error.
'**-2147217900:[MySQL 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.7.22-log] Unknown column 'Automated' in 'field list'**'

```vb
    With wsBooks
        For rowCursor = 2 To 3
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO TestExperiment (Experiment_Name, Experiment_Method, Experiment_Analyst, Experiment_condition) " & _
                "VALUES ('" & esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 1)) & "', " & _
                "'" & esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 2)) & "', " & _
                "'" & esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 3)) & "', " & _
                esc(.Cells(rowCursor, 4)) & ")"
            oConn.Execute strSQL
        Next
    End With
```

However when I push first two columns it works.

I believe I am making some mistake around here but I cannot figure out what, I tried to refer the MySQL Manual but could not get any solution.Thanks.

Comment: Add `Debug.Print strSQL` and make sure the output is what you expect, and that you can run that SQL in a client tool like the MySQL query browser

Comment: @TimWilliams in which part of the code 'Debug.Print strSQL' is supposed to be added?

Comment: Just before the Execute line.  Then check in the VB editor Immediate panel (Ctrl+G to show that if not visible)

Comment: Do NOT concatenate user-provided inputs into an executable SQL statement, EVER. Use parameters instead, so that you don't have to care for quoting and escaping (which I presume is what `esc` is doing). It's the server's job to deal with parameter types and values, not the client's.